# How to place a combobox in wxgrid (python)?

Tags: python, wxpython

I can't find any good information on how to place a combobox inside a cell in a wxgrid. I tried Google, but maybe I'm blind. Anyone have a simple sample to share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [GridChoiceCellEditor](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor-class.html). You can use it as follows:

```
    choice_editor = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(choices_list, True) 
    grid.SetCellEditor(row, col, choice_editor)
```

Answer (score 1):

The wxPython demo has an example that shows how this is done in the GridStdEdRend.py file itself or from within the demo itself, see the "Editors and Renderers Demo" part of the grid demo. What you're looking for is the GridCellChoiceEditor. See also: http://wiki.wxpython.org/GridCellChoiceEditor

Comment: This seems to limit the display to looking like a cell when not being clicked... and only changes to a combobox when clicked on.